# FreeTDS Mac OS X MiniPortile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, freetds

I'm trying to install FreeTDS on Max OS X Lion and came across the MiniPortile GitHub repository.

https://github.com/luislavena/mini_portile

I'm trying to install FreeTDS so that I can use the sqladapter

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds

The instructions on the sqladapter github say to clone the mini_portile repo then just do:

```
$ bundle install
$ rake compile
$ rake native gem
$ gem install pkg/tiny_tds-X.X.X-#{platform}.gem
```

I don't understand how to use the library.

I tried cloning the repo, switching to my local clone, and running:

```
bundle install
```

but there is no Gemfile.

Do I need to include the mini_portile library in a Rails application, and then run the commands?

I'm missing a step in the step by step directions of how to use mini_portile to install FreeTDS on Mac OS X.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run those commands on the tiny_tds project, not the miniportile one