# Homebrew, FreeTDS, tiny_tds. Why can't I install tiny_tds after successfully installing FreeTDS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, freetds, tiny-tds

This issue led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004464/failing-to-bundle-install-tiny-tds-on-mac-os-x-10-8-with-homebrew-freetds).

I expected that to solve my issue, a couple of the answers there detail some config params that can help with the installation. The paths weren't quite right for me so I modified them and ended up with this:

```
gem install tiny_tds -- --with-freetds-include=/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.21/include   
    --with-freetds-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.21/lib
    --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/include
    --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib
```

However, running that has resulted in the same error I was getting earlier. As follows:

[image: Console error]

I previously installed libiconv and FreeTDS using `brew`.

Has anyone encountered and solved this issue on OS X El Capitan?

If you'd like any more information please just ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hallelujah!**

After trying absolutely everything I could think of, including reading the mkmf.log file and a plethora of different installation parameters, I've arrived at a solution that worked for me.

In the end, the solution was relatively straight-forward, though difficult to figure out. The issue was that it was trying to build with the wrong architecture in mind (32-bit). Using the flag `ARCHFLAGS` to explicitly specify 64-bit, the installation worked immediately, as follows:

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install tiny_tds
```

I hope somebody finds this useful--I didn't find anything anywhere saying this was a solution.

Comment: awesome man! thanks a lot, I thought that it was not able to find freetds